# How to click the login button using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="login" id="login">
<div class="top">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="language">
        <div class="language-show" ng-click="showLanguageList($event)"><span title="English" class="current-language" id="current_language">English</span></div>
        <div class="language-list" id="language_list" style="display: none;" ng-click="changeLanguage($event)"><div title="English" class="out" id="en" onmouseover='this.className="over"' onmouseout='this.className="out"'>English</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<table class="middle" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td class="login-l">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="login-m">
            <div class="login-part">
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="login-error">
                    <div class="inputValidTip ng-hide" ng-show="szErrorTip!=''"><i class="error"></i><label class="ng-binding"></label></div>
                </div>
                <div class="login-user">
                    <input class="login-input ng-valid ng-dirty" id="username" type="text" maxlength="32" placeholder="User Name" autocomplete="off" ng-model="username">
                    <i class="icon-user"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="login-item">
                    <input class="login-input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope" style="display: none;" type="text" maxlength="16" ng-model="password"><input class="login-input ng-valid ng-dirty" id="password" type="password" maxlength="16" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" pigsney=""><span class="pigsney close" style="left: 210px; top: 7px; display: inline-block;" onselectstart="return false;"></span>
                    <i class="icon-pass"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="login-item bottom">
                    <span class="pwd-link ng-binding ng-hide" ng-click="forgetPwd()" ng-show="oCap.bSptGuidImport || oCap.bSptQAReset" ng-bind="oLan.forgetPwd">Forgot password?</span>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary login-btn" type="button" ng-click="login()"><label class="ng-binding" ng-bind="oLan.login">Login</label></button>
                </div>
                <!--<div class="login-item anonymous" ng-show="anonymous">
                    <span ng-bind="oLan.anonymous" ng-click="login('anonymous')"></span>
                </div>-->
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="login-r">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
<div class="footer" id="footer"></div>
```

I want to lick login button.

```
button class="btn btn-primary login-btn" type="button" ng-click="login()
```

How can I find this element?
I used Python.
And, `find_element_by_css_selector()`.

The web source is from some embedded machine. So, I can't use the Chrome.
I can't find the xpath on IE because I am a beginner.

Please, help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the element using its class name, you can do it like:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Login']")
button.click()
```

Comment: Thanks! But, I got the error message. "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find element with css selector == .btn btn-primary login-btn"

Comment: You can't use 3 classes in `find_element_by_class_name`.

Comment: @KEVIN i have edited the ans. Please pick the new answer and let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks. But, Same. Unable to find element with xpath == //button[text()='Login']

Comment: @KEVIN please check if there is any iframe present in the html structure.

Comment: No ifram in the html source.

Comment: @KEVIN can you tell me the link on which you are trying? I’ll check and let you know the correct xpath

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so `click()` the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-primary.login-btn[ng-click^='login']>label.ng-binding[ng-bind$='login']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary login-btn' and starts-with(@ng-click, 'login')]/label[@class='ng-binding' and text()='Login']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks. But,  can't click. Message: Cannot click on element

Comment: @KEVIN Update the question with the complete error stack trace please.

Comment: Thanks! But, same message. Message: Cannot click on element

Answer (score 0):

You can locate an element with "Login" text in its child. You can also add a scroll to the element before the click

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[label[.="Login"]]')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

Comment: Thanks. But, it can't click. Message: Cannot click on element

Comment: File "D:\Project\Study\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: Cannot click on element

Comment: @KEVIN add `driver.maximize_window()` after the driver creation.

Comment: Thanks. But, same. Message: Cannot click on element

Answer (score 0):

First wait element to be clickable

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, //button[text()='Login']"")))
```

Then use some JSExecutor to click it.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Login']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```